# Diagonal array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

If I have the array `[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]` (let's call it So) which is done as `numpy.eye(3)`.
How can I get that the elements below the diagonal are only 2 and 3 like this `[[1,0,0],[2,1,0],[3,2,1]]` ?? How can I assign vectors of an array to a different set of values?

I know I could use `numpy.concatenate` to join 3 vectors and I know how to change rows/columns but I can't figure out how to change diagonals below the main diagonal.

I tried to do `np.diagonal(So,-1)=2*np.diagonal(So,-1)` to change the diagonal right below the main diagonal but I get the error message `cannot assign to function call`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not start from `numpy.eye` but rather [`numpy.ones`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) and use [`numpy.tril`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html)+[`cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) to compute the next numbers on the lower triangle:

```
import numpy as np
np.tril(np.ones((3,3))).cumsum(axis=0).astype(int)
```

output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```

###### reversed output (from comment)

Assuming the array is square

```
n = 3
a = np.tril(np.ones((n,n)))
(a*(n+2)-np.eye(n)*n-a.cumsum(axis=0)).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [3, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 1]])
```

Output for `n=5`:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 5, 1, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 5, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]])
```

Comment: Thats nice! I didn't know about cumsum function
And do you an idea how to do it if the output wanted was [[1,0,0],[3,1,0],[2,3,1]]?
Thank you :)

Comment: @Gon it depends, what would be the output for a 4x4 array? And 5x4?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want but I provided an update

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.fill_diagonal` and index the matrix so the principal diagonal of your matrix is the one you want. This suposing you want to put other values than 2 and 3 is the a good solution:

```
import numpy as np

q = np.eye(3)


#if you want the first diagonal below the principal
# you can call q[1:,:] (this is not a 3x3 or 2x3 matrix but it'll work)

val =2
np.fill_diagonal(q[1:,:], val)
#note that here you can use an unique value 'val' or 
# an array with values of corresponding size
#np.fill_diagonal(q[1:,:], [2, 2])

#then you can do the same on the last one column

np.fill_diagonal(q[2:,:], 3)
```

Comment: That's very clever! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could follow this approach:

```
def func(n):
...     return np.array([np.array(list(range(i, 0, -1)) + [0,] * (n - i)) for i in range(1, n + 1)])

func(3)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```